# Does hive jdbc support java.sql.PreparedStatement?

Tags: jdbc, hive

I am trying to query hive using `java.sql.PreparedStatemen`t and getting an empty result set, Same query giving proper resultset when executed using `java.sql.Statement`. I am using hive jdbc 1.2.2 jar and hives server is in Hortonworks hdp stack.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does:

> public class `HivePreparedStatement` extends HiveStatement implements `java.sql.PreparedStatement`

As can be seen, internally Hive does implement the JDBC interface `PreparedStatement` and thus, the driver supports this JDBC feature.

For reference see: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HivePreparedStatement.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Can you give some sample code for instantiating and inserting to hive tables with parameters using this HivePreparedStatment

Answer (score 0):

Only formally.

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ab4c53de82d4aaa33706510441167f2df55df15e/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HivePreparedStatement.java#L116

```java
    private String updateSql(String sql, HashMap<Integer, String> parameters) throws SQLException {
        List<String> parts = this.splitSqlStatement(sql);
        StringBuilder newSql = new StringBuilder((String)parts.get(0));

        for(int i = 1; i < parts.size(); ++i) {
            if (!parameters.containsKey(i)) {
                throw new SQLException("Parameter #" + i + " is unset");
            }

            newSql.append((String)parameters.get(i));
            newSql.append((String)parts.get(i));
        }

        return newSql.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thats quite laconic. You may want to clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).